# Is the Conover-Iman post-hoc test is better to use than Dunn's with small samples size after the KW test since it use the t-test on the ranks?

Tags: small-sample, kruskal-wallis-test, dunn-test

I know that we use the t-distribution to be able to know if two small-size samples with a normal distribution (n < 30) are different or not (Student's t-test).  If we have a bigger sample with a normal distribution (n > 30), then we can use the z distribution. So with this information, can I assume that the Conover-Iman post-hoc test is a better test to use than the Dunn test after the Kruskal-Wallis test to compare small-size samples because it uses the t-test instead of the z-test on the ranks?  It is the the Dunn test that uses the z-test on the ranks.

Comment: 1. I dispute the premise that using a z-test when n>30 is always suitable, even when the population is (somehow) known to be normally distributed.  I know some books say things like this, but without good (or indeed, typically *any*) support for the claim.  2. Ranks are certainly not normally distributed; the reasoning here cannot rely on your initial premise, even if it were true.

Comment: Thanks for the information,

Comment: The hope was that you might reframe the question to avoid relying on such premises. A question like "With a Kruskal-Wallis, is the Conover-Iman post-hoc test actually better to use than Dunn's, and if so, what makes it better?" would avoid it. If you particularly seek a more detailed correction of the premises (i.e. a frame challenge answer), you could leave it

Comment: For now, I'm good, but for the next question that I will have, that is a good suggestion. Thanks again,

Comment: Hi Simon. Welcome to CV! I am the author of both the [dunn.test](https://cran.r-project.org/package=dunn.test) and [conover.test](https://cran.r-project.org/package=conover.test) (Conover-Iman) packages in R (and the corresponding Stata packages). I can tell you that as a *post hoc* pairwise test following rejection of a Kruskal-Wallis null hypothesis, the Conover-Iman test always has greater statistical power than Dunn's test. Dunn's test was published 15 years earlier, and is better known, but I would use the Conover-Iman test if I had the choice to do so.

Comment: I would go with the Dwass-Steel-Crichtlow-Fligner's test (DSCF). It has a specific approach to controlling the familywise error rate (FWER) built in, uses the ranks from the Kruskal-Wallis test, and, uses the pooled variance implied by the null hypothesis in the Kruskal-Wallis test.